# get mp3 files from path

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm trying to get mp3 files from a folder path of my system to list it in my listView, but unfortunately there's always the same error. (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array)

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
}
}

private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString());

public void searchForSongs() {

    ListView listView;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    File f = new File(SD_PATH);

   try {

          if (f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0){
           for (File file : f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())){
                  list.add(file.getName());
              }
       }

    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        textView2.setText(""+e);
        return;
    }

    final ArrayAdapter songList = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(songList);
}
```

Comment: You should at least post the full stack trace - it would help to know what line the NPE is coming from so we can figure out what exactly is null that shouldn't be null. So if the error is on line 73 you should indicate which line is line 73.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you have no .mp3 files on `SD_PATH` or your `Mp3Filter` is not working

Comment: @NitroNbg There are files on my SD_PAth and the Mp3Filter should work. I think the error appears because SD_Path is the wrong path

Comment: ```listFiles``` returns ```null``` if abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs. Are you sure that your app has the I/O permission? By the way you already called ```toString``` on the ```SD_PATH``` so I don't think you need ```new String()```.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution use the following code to Read the `MP3` file from the Specific Folder..

First of all Create 1 Model class as Given Below, to `GET` and `SET` Files in list.

**AudioModel.class**

```
public class AudioModel {

    String aPath;
    String aName;
    String aAlbum;
    String aArtist;

    public String getaPath() {
        return aPath;
    }

    public void setaPath(String aPath) {
        this.aPath = aPath;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public String getaAlbum() {
        return aAlbum;
    }

    public void setaAlbum(String aAlbum) {
        this.aAlbum = aAlbum;
    }

    public String getaArtist() {
        return aArtist;
    }

    public void setaArtist(String aArtist) {
        this.aArtist = aArtist;
    }
}
```

Now We have our Model Class Now use the below code to Read the all MP3 files from your Folder.

**This will return list of all MP3 Files with Music `NAME, PATH, ARTIST, ALBUM` and if you wants more detail please refer `Media.Store.Audio` doc..** 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html

```
public List<AudioModel> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {

        final List<AudioModel> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,};
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%yourFolderName%"}, null);

        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                AudioModel audioModel = new AudioModel();
                String path = c.getString(0);
                String album = c.getString(1);
                String artist = c.getString(2);

                String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                audioModel.setaName(name);
                audioModel.setaAlbum(album);
                audioModel.setaArtist(artist);
                audioModel.setaPath(path);

                Log.e("Name :" + name, " Album :" + album);
                Log.e("Path :" + path, " Artist :" + artist);

                tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
            }
            c.close();
        }

        return tempAudioList;
    }
```

To Read Files of Specific Folder, use below Query and write your folder name in Query..

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                          projection, 
                                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
                                          new String[]{"%yourFolderName%"}, // yourFolderName 
                                          null);
```

If you wants All Files of device use below Query..

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                          projection, 
                                          null, 
                                          null, 
                                          null);
```

Don't forget to add Storage Permission .. enjoy.